# Serve static content from folder outside of project

Tags: spring, jhipster

I'm currently developing a Java backend together with JHipster 3 and ran into a problem I don't seem to be able to solve very easily.

I would like to serve static assets – in this case images – from a folder outside of the project in addition to the default front-end generated by JHipster. As of default JHipster seems to serve static assets from one directory out of two depending on environment, as configured in `main/java/config/WebConfigurer.java`. I would like to point `/public/**` to a folder in my home catalogue but keep the `/**` mapping for the Angular front-end.

In general Spring projects you seem to be able to add other sources for static assets by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and override the addResourceHandlers method, but that doesn't seem to have an effect in my case. Adding the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation breaks the default JHipster mapping for their front-end. If I don't add the annotation I don't even seem to reach `handleRequest()` in `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` which handles the mapping to the correct servlet.

I can't give any other information on the subject at the moment, but I'm hoping someone with knowledge on JHipster will see this and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, Max.

Answer (score 0):

All app servers have an option to provide additional locations for class path. 
For example, Tomcat's property is 'common.loader' in conf/catalina.properties.

You can then use e.g. Spring's *ClassPathResource* to load a resource manually, or just use a construct like '*@Value("classpath:abc.txt") Resource r*' to inject something known in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to serve assets from the file system and not from the class path. I want to add additional sources for serving static content beside the default source provided by JHipster.

Comment: I believe class path is the way to go. I am not familiar with JHipster, but your default source is most probably just some location relative to the class path.